# Is there a way to define a function permanently in jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, function

I'm working on a site that passes information to my server that returns a page, however I have to re-define the click listener every time I reload the page because jQuery controls all my clicks on every page, so I' m wondering is there a way to permanently define a function?

jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.lvl1Links').on('click',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('pload').html('<img src="source/image/lbl.gif">');
        var page = $(this).attr('id');
        var huh = $('input:hidden').val();
        var data = 'pop='+huh+'&page='+page;
        $.post('source/php/bots/authorize.php',data,function(data){
                $('#pager_master_div').html(data).slideDown();
                $('pload').html('');
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't permanently define things because the pages are not permanent. All of your links on every page do different things, so you have to tell the browser what to do for each individual link.

Answer (score 1):

Being a stateless platform, every time the page loads you need to rebind things like this. Here's the pattern I use to make it easier, though:

If this is common across an area of your site, put this type of stuff into an `init` function in the common file. e.g.

global.js:

```
function InitSalesPageOrWhatever(){
  $(function(){ foo; });
  OtherStuffThatRunsOnEverySalesPageLoad();
}
```

Then in the script block on your pages, e.g. SalesPage:

```
InitSalesPageOrWhatever();
```

That's it--just one line in your content pages. Beyond the benefit of the content pages being nice and clean, that big clump of JS can now be cached by the user's browser, making the load on you less and their experience faster.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery (and all Javascript) runs on the client side where permanence is unavailable. There are two ways to approach the permanence you seek.

1. Write a jQuery [plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and include it in your page.
2. Write your click handler once, and use your server-side code/scripting language to include it in every HTML page. An example PHP include is [here](http://php.net/manual/function.include.php).

This may be a good time to consider HTML templates -- documents that contain standard HTML (header, footer, navigation, etc) that should be included in every page of your site.